# How to append angular2 component to d3 selection?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am using Angular2 + d3js to draw a chart. There is a tooltip when moving mouse onto the chart. Currently I am appending a "div" to "body" directly and generate the innerHTML dynamically when moving mouse in the `d3.select("svg").on("mouseover", function(d){...}).`

```
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
      .attr("class", "tooltip")             
      .style("opacity", 10);

    d3.select("svg").on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);

        div.html("Tooltip Content Here")
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 10 + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
   });
```

Because I am using this in Angular2, I think the tooltip should be moved into another Component / Directive to separate the logic. A component may look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css']
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But how to append the created component to the mouseover function of d3.select("svg")? Or how to use the 'app-tooltip' selector in another component directly?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> Or how to use the 'app-tooltip' selector in another component
>   directly?

You just add the `component`'s selector to the other `component`, as you normally would. `<app-tooltip></app-tooltip>`. Don't forget to add it in `declarations` of `app.module.ts` (or at a level where the other `component` still can make use of it).

Example

**component1.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component1',
    templateUrl: 'component1.component.html'
})

export class Component1Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**component1.component.html**

```
<h1>This is component 1</h1>
<app-component2></app-component2>
```

**component2.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    templateUrl: 'component2.component.html'
})

export class Component2Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**component2.component.html**

```
<h3>This is component 2</h3>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Component1Component, Component2Component } from './components/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    AppComponent,
    Component1Component, Component2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-component1></app-component1>
```

**Result**

[image: Component in component]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Because there is no html written directly now. Everything is created by JavaScript dynamically. Is it possible to "move out" some html to other components and call these components directly from JavaScript directly while not use the tag `<app-component1></app-component1>` in app.component.html?

Comment: @NguDeveloper Did you ever found out how to add a component to a d3 selection?